# Looking for a matrix A(t)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need your help, I'm looking for a contraexample, I need to give a matrix A(t), such that $$e^{\int_0^tA(s)ds}$$
is not a matrix solution for $x'=A(t)x$. I really don't have any clue what can it be. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $e^{\int_{0}^{t}A(s)\,ds}x(0)$, or do you really mean for $x(t)$ to be a matrix?

Comment: Yes x(t) it's a matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is a concrete example where both the matrix exponential and the "integral"
( i.e. the fundamental solution of the corresponding matrix ODE ) is known:

Let $\sigma_3 = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$, 
$\sigma_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and consider 
$A(t) = t\sigma_3 + \sigma_1 = \begin{bmatrix}t & 1 \\ 1 & -t\end{bmatrix}$.
We have

$$\Lambda(t) \stackrel{def}{=} \int_0^t A(s) ds = \frac{t^2}{2}\sigma_3 + t\sigma_1$$

Notice $\;\Lambda(t)^2 = \lambda(t)^2 I_2\;$ where $\displaystyle\;\lambda(t) = t \sqrt{1 + \frac{t^2}{4}}\;$, the matrix exponential is given by

$$\begin{align}
{\large e^{\int_0^t A(s) ds} = e^{\Lambda(t)}}
&= \cosh\lambda(t) I_2 + \frac{\sinh\lambda(t)}{\lambda(t)}\Lambda(t)\\
&= \cosh\left(t\sqrt{1+\frac{t^2}{4}}\right) I_2 +
\frac{\sinh\left(t\sqrt{1+\frac{t^2}{4}}\right)}{\sqrt{1+\frac{t^2}{4}}}\left(\frac{t}{2}\sigma_3 + \sigma_1\right)
\end{align}
$$

The fundamental solution of the matrix ODE is the solution of following initial value problem.

$$X'(t) = A(t)X(t)\quad\text{ subject to }\quad X(0) = I_2\tag{*1}$$

Notice

$$X''(t) = A'(t) X(t) + A(t) X'(t) = ( A'(t) + A(t)^2 ) X(t) = (\sigma_3 + (1 + t^2)I_2) X(t)$$

Different entries of $X(t)$ decouple and they are solutions of ODE of the form

$$y''(t) = (\beta + 1 + t^2) y(t) \quad\text{ where }\quad \beta = \pm 1$$
The solutions of this sort of ODE are called [Parabolic cylinder function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function). They can also be expressed
in terms of the more familiar [confluent hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function). One can show that the fundamental solution 
of $(*1)$ is given by:

$$X(t) = e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
{}_1F_1(-\frac14;\frac12;-t^2) &
{}_1F_1(\frac14;\frac32;-t^2) t\\
{}_1F_1(\frac34;\frac32;-t^2) t &
{}_1F_1(\frac14;\frac12;-t^2)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

As one can see, even for something as simple as our $A(t)$ which is linear in $t$,
once $A(t)$ at different time fails to commute, the "integral" become very hard to
compute.

Comment: Do you have any reference for 'matrix exponential'? I cannot find anything tangible. Thanks.

Comment: @Krokop I don't have any specific reference nor do I remember where I learn this stuff.
But the important concept is the [norm of a matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm). Equipped with the norm, the matrix becomes a normed algebra.
Since the space of real/complex $n\times n$ matrices are finite dimensional, it is a 
[complete metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space). Provided we are careful in the order of taking products, we can perform the sum of any absolutely convergence series in any order we like.
Matrix exponential is simply one of the example.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The trouble occurs because of non-commuting matrices.  Almost any example where $A(s) A(t) \ne A(t) A(s)$ will work.  Of course it would be good to take an example where the integral and the matrix exponential are easy to compute.
Try something upper or lower triangular.

Comment: Yes it can be, unfortunately the exponential never is easy to compute

Comment: ^That's not true if you select a "nice" matrix. Try a $2 \times 2$ nilpotent matrix.

Comment: Or a $2 \times 2$ matrix of the form $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{bmatrix}$!

Comment: Or, as I suggested, an upper or lower triangular one.

Comment: Yeah, but if I select a nilpotent matrix, it is always a solution for x'=Ax